# Getting OneDrive folders in a hierarchy

Tags: .net, xamarin, office365

**The background**

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.365 0.1.1-alpha` bits to access OneDrive for Business from a Xamarin App (iOS to be specific).

The code I have right now looks like this to retrieve a list of folder.

```
var client = await EnsureClientCreated(context);
var fileResult = await client.Files.ExecuteAsync();
var folders = fileResult.CurrentPage.OfType<Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.Folder>();
```

The problem is that I get a list of Folder objects back, but there is no sense of hierarchy expept for a hint in the url path. I get all folders in my OneDrive no matter what position it has in the folder structure.

The URL looks something like for a folder in the root.

```
"https://tsse1008669-my.sharepoint.com/personal/someuser_some_domain_com/Documents/Shared"
```

However the `Childrens` collection contains 0 Children and there is nothing else to indicate that this is in the root or that it has a parent.

Also worth noting, my SharePoint experience is very limited! :)

**The question**

How do I access OneDrive for business using the "Microsoft Office 365 My Files Library for .NET" in a way so that I can navigate the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% sure if I got your question right.

Please give this a shot. This should give you an enumarable of all child folders of "my.sharepoint.com/personal/someuser_some_domain_com/Documents/Shared".

Let me know if this won't work for you.

```
IPagedEnumerable<IFileSystemItem> filesResults = 
                                  await client.Files["Shared"].ToFolder().Children.ExecuteAsync();

//youmight loop through all child folders  
 foreach (IFileSystemItem file in filesResults.CurrentPage) 
 {
    // do something
 }
```

HTH
Philipp

Comment: I'll try that out! What if you want all the folders in the root?